# unable to find stripe routing number generation API

Tags: php, stripe-payments, strip

I am working on a stripe connect custom account where I need to add a bank account as an external account 
by stripe.js we can do it as

```
stripe.createToken('bank_account', {
  country: 'US',
  currency: 'usd',
  routing_number: '110000000',
  account_number: '000123456789',
  account_holder_name: 'Jenny Rosen',
  account_holder_type: 'individual',
}).then(function(result) {
  // Handle result.error or result.token
});
```

means getting information from the user and passing it to API call but the problem is there is a country selection and on each country, routing number creation is different format is given on this link https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#supported-settlement is there any API to get these formats by country 
you can check the link below

[image]

Comment: Could be wrong, but I don't think stripe have an API that will provide this to you. You'll probably have to write the validation rules yourself.

Comment: @JonStirling is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the routing number yourself when you create the bank information. The page you show is only example data. You can validate the routing number locally before sending it to Stripe's API with the "check digit", or you can validate the routing number with the Stripe js API.

`Stripe.bankAccount.validateRoutingNumber(123456789)`

Or See the Wikipedia article also linked to from the Stripe documentation if you manually want to implement the check digit.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_routing_transit_number#Check_digit

Comment: but what about the fields i need to show, where user will enter the data on change of country these fields will be change how do i know what fields for what country is there any api which help me to develop this

Comment: I don't think I understand what it is you want. Do you want the user to switch country and have the bank information for that specific account be translated to another country routing number? I don't think that is entirely possible. They would need to create a separate bank account and provide the information each time

Comment: i want to add a bank account of user by my platform and i am confuse about how to get routing number from user

Comment: You just ask the user for the routing number. Just like their account number or IBAN

Comment: ok you means one field for enter routing number for expect this which country is there ??

Comment: Yeah have them enter both the country and the routing number

Comment: i was confuse  because when i changing  country to japan on this link https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#supported-settlement i am getting "When creating a bank via the API, combine the bank code and branch code to create a full routing number (e.g., 0123456). We also explicitly require the name of the person or business that owns the bank account, via the account_holder_name attribute."